# How to make inline-block elements heights line up without display:table-cell

Tags: html, css

I have some inline-block elements in css that are lined up vertically on the top but aren't lined up well on the bottom. I tried display: table-cell but now they won't wrap anymore and so go off the edge of the screen on the right, creating the undesired horizontal scrollbar. The first picture is the default when there is enough space, the second is what happens when the width of your browser window is too small, the third is with inline-block (misaligned), and the fourth is showing inline-block's wrapping power in action. I was hoping that there is a way to combine the fourth and first. Thank you for your time. [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using Flex layout instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by getting a stripped down wire-frame: http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/JKvARa

You could do this with classic floats and have a lot of control with small-screen first @media rules that cascade. You can see this stylus... (pseudo code if you don't use that syntax)

```
section
    width: 100%
    float: left
    padding: .5rem
    .card
        background: white
        padding: .5rem
.one
    border: 1px solid blue
    @media (min-width: 700px)
        width: 50%
        float: left
    @media (min-width: 1100px)
        width: 30%
.two
    border: 1px solid red
    @media (min-width: 700px)
        width: 50%
        float: left
    @media (min-width: 1100px)
        width: 30%
.three
    border: 1px solid green
    @media (min-width: 700px)
        width: 30%
        float: left
    @media (min-width: 1100px)
        width: 20%
.four
    border: 1px solid orange
    @media (min-width: 700px)
        width: 70%
        float: left
    @media (min-width: 1100px)
        width: 20%
```

Flex-box is also really great. I would build it with both and see which constraints you are ok with. They both have them.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem of the elements being different heights

Comment: The word height is not in the OP's question. Also, when the screen-size is appropriate flex-box may get involved. It's just another way of thinking about it.

Comment: The question is asking how to make the tops and bottoms line up well. If that doesn't mean they should be the same height, what does it mean?

Comment: It doesn't matter @quentin ~ time to move on. : )